# Postgres - unlimited text risk

Tags: sql, postgresql, security

The PostgreSQL `text` type allows me to store unlimited length strings. Then what prevents an user of my website to spam texts to fill up my database?

Should I never use `text` for user data and instead always limit length or is there a mechanism I'm not aware of?

**edit**: Sorry this question wasn't clear. Is was rather: Is there a risk of someone breaking my app by filling up my database if I don't limit the length of the user data sent to it? I've never heard of this kind of attack so I thought there might be something protecting me from it I wasn't aware of. Seems like there is a risk.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Are you asking as an DBA or application developer? I assume latter. You’re the one writing the data into the database so you can limit things however you want. You can always check the length of the data being input by the user.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If I limit the size on the application side why not limit as well in the DBA side? Sounds like a dumb question but is it a reality that my user could fill up my database if I didn't limit the size on one side or the other?

Comment: That depends on what your application does. I can’t tell you, you’re the only one that knows. And yes, you can add triggers and checks, but why do double limits that require you to build double error checks also and when they change you need to change two things?

Comment: Yovar - the point is that when you validate strings length in a client app you also prevent sending potentially enormous strings over the net.

Comment: @klin I understand that but someone might forge requests to fill my database.

Comment: If you need, you can easily implement a `check` constraint to limit the length of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it is a good idea to always limit it to prevent any known or unknown weakness or borderline situation. Unless you need it unlimited on purpose... but even in that case it is a best practice to validate the data at some level (for example at application level).

Comment: I agree, but I'd strongly recommend the database for (primary) validation checks, not the application. One day, there might be another application accessing the database and the restriction on the data might have been forgotten to be implemented there and ... The database is responsible of the data and has the authority over it, nothing else. Safest bet.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a huge risk and falls under a DoS attack vector (Resource exhaustion). `TEXT` columns can store up to 1gb of data per row.

You can mitigate this at various levels of your stack.

1. Ingress/Load balancers such as Nginx can quickly check `client_max_body_size` and drop the request.
2. Data/Schema validation on your writable API.
3. DB level check constraint e.g. `location_name TEXT NULL CHECK (location_name <> '' AND char_length(location_name) <= 64)` prevents empty strings and those larger than 64 characters.